# several graphs on one plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like, with this data set: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/mydata.csv , to display 4 different graphics: GA, N1, N2, PE in different shades. For each graphic, all values of category "m" must be displayed on the y axis, with "nbr" on the x axis.

Here's the code I have so far (thanks to @CMichael for most of this code)

```
require(reshape2)

mydata = read.csv(file="/Users/Rodolphe/Downloads/mydata.csv", sep=";", header=TRUE)
dataM = melt(mydata,c("nbr"))

#parse labels to identify vertical category and fill the value correspondingly
dataM$order = ifelse(grepl("GED",dataM$variable),"GED",ifelse(grepl("RAN",dataM$variable),"RAN",ifelse(grepl("EIG",dataM$variable),"EIG","BET")))
#parse labels to identify horizontal category and fill the value correspondingly
dataM$net = ifelse(grepl("PE",dataM$variable),"PE",ifelse(grepl("GA",dataM$variable),"GA",ifelse(grepl("N1",dataM$variable),"N1","N2")))
#parse label to identify category
dataM$category = ifelse(grepl("mNC",dataM$variable),"mNC",ifelse(grepl("aSPL",dataM$variable),"aSPL",ifelse(grepl("d",dataM$variable),"d","m")))


ggplot(dataM[dataM$category=="m" & dataM$order=="RAN",], aes(value, fill=net)) + geom_density(alpha = .3, color=NA)  + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

Which gives me:

[image]

That's, aesthetically, exactly what I need. The display is obviously wrong, however, and several things confuse me. For one thing, I can't seem to force "nbr" on the x axis. Am I on the right track at all with this code?

Comment: Looking at your dataset, I'm not sure what the problem is. `nbr` looks like a case ID, or sample number, or some such. Why would you want to plot it on the x-axis? In your data, GA, N1, N2, and PE have values on [0,10], and you are plotting the density functions of those values.

Comment: How is it obviously wrong?

Comment: @jlhoward : It is actually quite like a time series, where nbr would act as "t" would in an actual time series. But I think I understand what you mean: I'm filling under the curves in order to better distinguish them, but they aren't density at all. I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: @rawr I just realized it's not a density plot that I need, but a regular plot that would be filled by a colour, in order to distinguish the "net" I'm plotting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on OP's comments, this might be one way to plot the data:

```
ggplot(dataM[dataM$category=="m" & dataM$order=="RAN",], aes(x=nbr, y=value, fill=net)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=value),alpha=0.3)+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

[image]

Or, IMHO a better option:

```
ggplot(dataM[dataM$category=="m" & dataM$order=="RAN",], aes(x=nbr, y=value, fill=net)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=net))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=value),alpha=0.3)+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")+
  facet_grid(net~.)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

based on OP's comments, this might be one way to plot the data:

```
ggplot(dataM[dataM$category=="m" & dataM$order=="RAN",], aes(x=nbr, y=value, fill=net)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0, ymax=value),alpha=0.3)+ 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```